# Avoid duplicate code in Excel IF formula code

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to avoid duplicate code within excel formulas. Is there a method to repeat a certain code segment?

```
=IF(A1=1,(A1-B2-C3),(A1-B2-C3)+1)
```

This would be especially useful when it comes to more complex or longer sections. But: everything must be in ONE formula in ONE cell. Thanks! :-)

EDIT: This is my current code.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".amp",A2)),IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))+1,SEARCH(".html",A2)-FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))-5),""),IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))+1,SEARCH(".html",A2)-FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""))))-1),""))
```

It strips the long ID number out of any URL of a specific CMS. So

```
FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","#",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")))
```

is probably the part which occurs more than once and should be replaced for a code which does not be that duplicate-prone.

*EXAMPLE: www.domain.com/path1/path2/this-is-an-article-123-dd-123456789.html --> 1234567890
EXAMPLE: www.domain.com/path1/path2/this-is-an-article-123-dd-1234567890.amp.html -> 
1234567890 
EXAMPLE: www.domain.com/path1/this-is-an-article-1234567890.html -> 
1234567890*

Comment: `=IF(A1=1,0,1)+(A1-B2-C3)`

Comment: Thanks very much! I wanted to express that this was an example - in reality, it may contain of something much more complex. E.g. IF(A1=1,COMPLEXFORMULA1_WITH_NUMBER_RESULT,COMPLEXFORMULA1_WITH_NUMBER_RESULT-1+A3/F7) .. or is your method also working in this case?

Comment: It seems like you can still apply the same principle to that complex formula - keep the `1+A3/F7` inside and move the `COMPLEXFORMULA1_WITH_NUMBER_RESULT` outside.

Comment: Please tell me if I am too demanding. I still have some problems in applying your helpful assistance.... So this is my actual code I would like to slim.... see Code edit above.

Comment: Put this in question and edit the question instead. Comments are harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; did so! :-)

Comment: Please include: Input samples and expected output sample. There might just be a smarter way to do what you try to do. And tell us which of the two apps you are using: Excel or Google Sheets. They operate differently.

Comment: I added two examples - I need the longest number - an article ID - in any URL to be extracted.

Comment: So would the article ID always be the longest number? And would it always be between say 9-10 numbers?

Comment: The article ID will be always the longest number. The amount of numbers can vary, unfortunately. Although it mainly consists of 8+ digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google sheets, you could use `REGEXEXTRACT` to get what you want:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{8,}")
```

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't think of such a simple solution yet.

Comment: By the way, I learned that Regex/REGEXTRACT is not supported by Excel without using VBA. Do you think my formula for excel is appropriate as I sometimes also need excel - or do you see any potential for a more slim formula?

Comment: Well, probably but since it's not supported in Excel (and if you don't want to use an UDF) you'll need to define some rules under which conditions you can extract the number. Also which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Office Professional Plus 2016. I just feel that my existing excel formula - see post - works, but is somewhat far away from being perfect...

Answer (score 1):

Place the complex common sub-expression in its own cell and refer to that cell.

**EDIT#1:**

As an alternative, you can use a *Named Formula* for the sub-expression:

[Named Formula](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/save-effort-by-defining-names-for-excel-2007-formulas/)

Comment: To be honest, I tried to avoid this. I would like to have a slim formula which works for itself. Additionally, although the formulas always keep the same, the references to a specific cell may change. (A1 gets A2, A3, A4 e.g.)

Comment: @David  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student - thanks so much again. Named Formula is a really interesting concept!! But in my first approach I have to ensure that the Article id extracting code works for everyone without predefining a named formula. So I can send this formula code to anybody - and he can use it without any preconditions or pre-work to do....

Answer (score 0):

So here is another way of finding the code in Excel:

[image: Solution]

Here is the formula in Cell `B1` which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then drag it down to apply across board:

```
{=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,LARGE(IF(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1)="-",ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))),1)+1,LEN(A1)),".","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[1]")}
```

For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).

Cheers :)

Ps. it seems that `GoogleSheet` has out performed `Excel` in some area already.